# Why do power rails on breadboards omit connection points?

Tags: breadboard, prototyping

It seems most solderless breadboards don't have the connection points on the power rails aligned to the rest of the connection points.

Some just omit every 6th; on some the gap isn't even a multiple of 0.1 inches so some points don't line up at all.

I think for some usual applications it would be convenient if the power rails were aligned to the rest of the board. For example, to connect one side of a DIP-switch or bar graph LED to one of the rails all at once.

Is there a practical reason for this misalignment?

[image: photo of a solderless breadboard showing non-aligned connection pins]

Comment: no, there is no reason, other than bad design and copying a bad design

Comment: Well the practical reason is that it doesn't matter since there are no ICs that would fit even if they were aligned.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well - no ICs but as mentioned there are DIP-switches, bar graph-LEDs and alike.

Comment: They will wouldn't line up though. I do not believe that the gap is in increments of 0.100"

Comment: That is one of the reasons, that got me thinking - actually the rail is spaced 0.3 inches apart from the conncetion points, so "dip formfactor stuff" would fit, if they would line up w/o gaps in the other direction. Of cource only convenient, if on side of the component needs to connect all pins to same power level… (like e.g. dip-sw and gb-led)

Comment: Oh it is a multiple? I see.

Comment: At least on my breadboards (and I have numerous "brands") - the jigsaw-connectors aren't compatible, the spacing in rail direction differs - but all have work area spaced 0.3 inches from power rails…

Comment: The spacing varies by manufacturer, some line up, some don't.

Comment: Well - as they are not aligned in rail direction the spacing only matters if using bending gauge bending e.g. resistors to have 0.1"*X spacing… (still I own at least 5 "brands" all 0.3" spaced).
If they WERE - they probably would be more standardised in that way, too ^^

Comment: I've never seen breadboards like this. All my breadboards are aligned. It would drive me crazy if I can't tidy up my wiring because the power rails are misaligned. And they're not even misaligned a reasonable angle like 45 degrees! That's like what.. 22 degrees or something?

Comment: Mine line up with (a subset of) the main holes in your vertical dimension, but horizontally they seem to come in at 0.35" for one orientation of the jigsaw connectors, or 0.5" for the other

Comment: @slebetman 45 degrees is the unreasonable angle because it contains non-repeating digits. Not nice like 22, 44, or 66 degree angles.

Comment: Anecdotal I know, but I've never seen a breadboard where the power rail holes didn't line up with the working area.   Maybe get a new breadboard....

Comment: Well some of mine also are aligned - but the Q also was about the gaps. And theboard on the photo just featured both misalignment and gaps. Preventing most components to plug in b/c they are often 5+ pins (like the mentioned dip-sw etc.).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The contacts are manufactured in strips with a space between every 5 where they cut them apart to make the main contacts, then they use the same strips for the power rails and cut them to whatever length they need for the size of breadboard.

Comment: I see… too bad the "practical" aspect is on the producers side - had some hope for "hidden feature" for users ^^

Comment: One mine at least, the space maintains separation, so there's simply a missing hole.  That means still only blocks of 5 holes but at least they line up

Comment: Yes. But some (judging by online listings i saw many) gaps are not sized in multiples of 0.1 inches.
Also the limit of 5 connection points rules out many components (e.g. the bar graph led blocks which sparked the Q for me).

Comment: Everyone who has an old beat-up power-surge-singed breadboard socket should take it apart and look at the metal strips with finger contacts.

Answer (score 9):

So some amateur doesn't try to insert an IC between the working area and the power rail. It was done on purpose.

Comment: Somewhat reasonable. Still… i would prefer a fried IC (and having learned something ^^) over the misalignment and connecting manny pins to the same rail separately for each pin for each bar graph for the rest of my life ;)

Comment: Maybe there is a missed opportunity out there for a new design. No rules prevent you from launching a new product.  I heard there are a bunch of empty booths at CES2022 if you can get it done for a New product launch by Friday in Vegas.

Comment: XD will not fly to vegas… Also don't see my future in producing better breadboards (not friday, not in the long run).

Comment: I don't think that would be very high on the manufacturers priority list. Even if you plugged an IC in with one row of pins in the bus, it wouldn't necessarily damage it, there's more chance of someone destroying an IC by just wiring it incorrectly. Breadboards were originally designed for engineers anyway, so there would be some expectation of competence. They would on the other hand do this to save costs, they're already making strips with groups of 5 contacts, so why not just use those for the buses too?

Comment: I think the main reason would be the Answer I selected "acceped".
I some cases I already used the 5-long rails for power distribution - but recently I plugged bar graph leds over the whole breadboard - continuous power rail would have been nice - so I wondered why it is not…

Comment: Also if using the 5-long on one side - it is still only 5-long (8-led bar graph e.g. are quite useful for 8-bit-stuff) - and more important: the oposing side would also be shorted…

Comment: I have 7 breadboards of various vintages going back decades, and only the newest one has offset power rails. So this seems to be a recent development.

Comment: @GodJihyo, you said, "Breadboards were originally designed for engineers anyway, so there would be some expectation of competence".  First, that's funny because I make things idiot-proof for engineers and technicians every day.  One example would be the alarm on a fluke hand-held meter when you switch to volts when you still have the cables plugged into the amps port.   That alarm is not for the general public, it is on a $400 meter for professionals.  And, breadboarding in my facility is typically done by technicians. Any engineer adjusting designs over a breadboard gets ridiculed.

Comment: @GTElectronics, do you have a source on the claim that it was done on purpose? A statement from an early designer, for example. Or is this just post-facto rationalization?

Answer (score 5):

The gaps are for tabs that hold the metal rails to the plastic, so that they don't come apart.

Removing the back of a breadboard shows the structure. On some breadboards the back is glued and removing it will damage it, but here is a picture courtesy of [Sparkfun tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard/anatomy-of-a-breadboard):

[image: Breadboard backside]

As can be seen, the metal is continuous but there are small spikes that go into plastic to hold it in place.

Comment: Those aren't really tabs holding the strips in place, they're just a flattened part of the strip. The metal strip is bent in a U where the contacts are, with these little flat parts in between where they're going to cut them (makes it easier to cut without deforming them). The contacts in the holes are more than enough to hold them in place.

Comment: @GodJihyo Hmm, after watching some youtube videos, I think you are right!

Answer (score 3):

> **It seems most solderless breadboards don't have the connection points on the power rails aligned to the rest of the connection points.**

This is not true of all solderless breadboards.

[image]

K & H AD-102 Advanced Solderless Breadboard - 456 Tie Points

As others have said, the gaps in the power rail tie-points *appear* to be simply a manufacturing convenience.

Comment: Well they are aligned - but the power rails have gaps…

Comment: Two missing holes, not just one? I've not seen that before, and I've been using breadboard of this general nature since high school, (mumble) decades ago. Always one missing hole, due to the how the metal strip underneath is made.